# ansible AWX добавление списка машин в файл инвентаря

Tags: ansible, active-directory, awx

Имеется домен на винде из ад скриптом на повершеле выгружается список машин по типу os и падает в текстовый файл, который представляет из себя dns имена машин,как-то можно сделать автоматическую синхронизацию инвентаря в awx (внутри контейнера) с этим текстовым файлом, который будет генерироваться с определенной переодичностью? В целевом сегменте сети нет выхода в интернет чтобы можно было использовать возможности смарт инвентаря.

Comment: Ну а где файл-то лежит? Который `dns-имена машин`?

Comment: на домен контроллере, на нем отрабатывается скрипт

Comment: Ну значит `- shell: mount.cifs && - slurp: /tmp/list`.